# Evaluate the Beta(3,1) and Beta(91,11) probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, beta-function

In [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/09/27/bayesian-amazon/) there is one diagram

[image]

And a statement:

> After observing 90 positive reviews and 10 negative reviews, our posterior estimate on $θ_A$ has a $beta(91, 11)$ distribution. After observing 2 positive reviews, our posterior estimate on $θ_B$ has a $beta(3, 1)$ distribution. The probability that a sample from $θ_A$ is bigger than a sample from $θ_B$ is 0.713.

Now I am trying to understand how to get this 0.713?

What I know for Beta distribution the first moment (mean) is:

$E(X) = \Large \frac{a}{a + b}$

I can find the mean for the $\mu_{A} = \frac{91}{102} =0.892$ (red)

I can find the mean for the $\mu_{B} = \frac{3}{4} =0.75 $ (blue)

---

PDF:
$f(x)=\frac{1}{B(a, b)} x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}, \quad x \in(0,1)$

Probability density function PDF(A):
$\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{B(91,11)} x^{90}(1-x)^{10} & 0<x<1 \\ 0 & \text { (otherwise) }\end{array}\right.$

Probability density function PDF(B):
$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}3 x^{2} & 0<x<1 \\ 0 & \text { (otherwise) }\end{array}\right.$

---

I can approximate the blue curve with the line $y=3x$, and the average $y$ value will be 1.5

The red curve I can possible approximate with Normal distribution, with the mean of 0.892, and variance 0.03056 because of

$ Beta(a, b)$ as $Normal \left(\frac{a}{a+b}, \sqrt{\frac{ab}{\left(a+b\right)^{2}\left(a+b+1\right)}}\right)$

Now the peak of the normal distribution should be $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is ~13. If I create a triangle from normal distribution with the height 13 and bottom $2*\sigma$, this means the average $y=6.5$.

Again I cannot find 0.713.

Any idea how John Cook found it?

Comment: Well, how would you find $\Pr[X > Y]$ in general, given two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ whose distributions you know?

Comment: I know for normal distribution the surface under the bell curve, from left to right (till some condition). There was one example with average height of man and woman. Both are  normal distribution with mean man greater than woman, and some sigmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\theta_A$ has the PDF $\frac{101!}{90!10!} x^{90} (1-x)^{10}$ for $x \in [0,1]$, and $\theta_B$ has the PDF $3x^2$ for $x \in [0,1]$, and they're independent, then their joint PDF is
$$
     \frac{3 \cdot 101!}{90! 10!} x^{90} (1-x)^{10} y^2
$$
for $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$. To find the probability $\theta_A > \theta_B$, integrate over the region where $x > y$:
$$
   \int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac{3 \cdot 101!}{90! 10!} x^{90} (1-x)^{10} y^2 \,dy\,dx = \frac{4991}{7004} \approx 0.713.
$$
We can also approximate by an easier integral: since $\theta_A$ has expected value $\frac{91}{102}$, and is pretty concentrated around that value, we could estimate $\Pr[\theta_A > \theta_B]$ as $\Pr[\frac{91}{102} > \theta_B] = \int_0^{91/102} 3x^2\,dx$. This gives us $(\frac{91}{102})^3 \approx 0.710$, which is pretty close.

Comment: What program do you use to calculate the symbolic math? I need one now for double integral.

Comment: I was using Mathematica, but you can certainly do this calculation in Wolfram Alpha: [here's how](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+3%2Fbeta%2891%2C11%29+x%5E90+%281-x%29%5E10+y%5E2+for+x%3D0+to+1+and+y%3D0+to+x), with bonus calculating-the-beta-function thrown in

Comment: Great I used `\int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac{3 \cdot 101!}{90! 10!} x^{90} (1-x)^{10} y^2 \,dy\,dx` and it worked, few minutes ago. Thanks for the Mathematica tip, hopefully there is some free version.

Answer (score 1):

The variables $\theta_A$ and $\theta_B$ are the posterior estimates for the proportion of positive reviews.  If these are independent (which is assumed to be the case), then $$\Pr[\theta_A > \theta_B] = \int_{\theta = 0}^1 \Pr[\theta_A > \theta]f_{\theta_B}(\theta) \, d\theta = \int_{\theta = 0}^1 \int_{\psi = \theta}^1 f_{\theta_A}(\psi) f_{\theta_B}(\theta) \, d\psi \, d\theta,$$ where $f_{\theta_A}$ and $f_{\theta_B}$ are the respective posterior densities, which we are told are beta distributed.  Thus
$$\Pr[\theta_A > \theta_B] = \frac{\Gamma(91+11)}{\Gamma(91)\Gamma(11)}\frac{\Gamma(3+1)}{\Gamma(3)\Gamma(1)} \int_{\theta=0}^1 \int_{\psi = \theta}^1 \psi^{90} (1-\psi)^{10} \theta^2 \, d\psi \, d\theta.$$